# Getting all apples in minimum time

Tags: algorithm

There are M apples (0<=M<=7) each in different place located along straight road.

Each apple gets perished after time limit. You must take all M apples.

So you need to find out the order in which   you should take the apples before their perishing deadlines and starting from most suitable position.

An apple j is located at distance d[j] from leftmost end of road.Time it takes to take apple is instantaneous and assume that one unit distance can be traveled in 1 unit of time.Find smallest time by which you can take all the apples.

Example : Let their be 5 apples and the following five lines shows pairs each showing

```
(distance ,time to perish)
(1,3)
(3,1)
(5,8)
(8,19)
(10,15)
```

Here minimum time will be 11.

**EDIT** : What if M goes to larger values say 50 or 100?

Obviously then brute force will not be working

Comment: Constraints are too small, can't you simply apply brute force.

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja I am not able to reach a brute force solution for this problem.And what if constraints go large ?

Comment: I have added brute force solution, and thinking about optimized.Will get back here, if able to devise a better solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have seen something very like this here before, but I cannot find it at the moment: I will try and reconstruct something based on my memories. I will ignore the fixed number of apples given.

Can the best answer ever finish on an apple in the interior of the line? Suppose it does, then just before you pick up the last apple you have picked up apples on both sides of it. But then you must have traveled from one side of the final apple to the other, so you would have done better to pick up what is now the final apple as you went past it. So the best solution must finish by picking up either the apple on the extreme left or the apple on the extreme right.

Suppose that you know the best possible cost of solving the problem for the leftmost N-1 apples and traveling to the rightmost of those N-1 apples. Then you can work out the best possible cost for a solution which finishes on the rightmost apple of all - it is just the N-1 + possible travel cost and the cost of moving one step. Given similar information, you can work out the best possible cost of a solution which finishes on the leftmost apple of all. Given these two costs you can work out the best possible cost to pickup all N apples and then travel, if necessary, to the leftmost (rightmost) apple of those N.

This is obviously going towards a dynamic programming or memoisation solution. There are less than 2N^2 sub-problems of the form "find the minimum cost under constraints of solving the problem for a contiguous interval of k apples and then traveling, if necessary, to the leftmost (rightmost) of those k apples". Given the best solutions for problems of size k you can work out the best solutions for problems of size k+1. So this can be solved using dynamic programming by building up a table of all partial solutions using entries of size k to build entries of size k+1 or by memoisation, using recursion to ask for the solutions of size k while solving problems of size k+1, but building up a table of solutions found so far so that you never have to solve the same sub-problem twice. In either case the time taken goes up as some polynomial in N, which is cheaper than N!.

Comment: Can you please write it in some better way like psudo code or so ?

Answer (score 0):

Try all permutations of `{1, 2,..., M}`. It never makes sense to start from a location which isn't one of the "apple-spots". The permutation tells you the order in which you pick up the apples. Find the minimum time taken over all these permutations. This runs in time `O(M*M!)`, which will be fast enough for your limits.